# Different result between Javascript and Java regular expression matches

Tags: java, regex

Now I am trying to match some patterns from a String containing elasticsearch's structured bulk requests. Here is an example:

```
index {[event_20191209][event][null], source[{"haha":"haha","jaja":"jaja"}]}, update {[event_20191209][event][xxx], doc_as_upsert[false], doc[index {[null][_doc][null], source[{"haha":"haha","jaja":"jaja"}]}], scripted_upsert[false], detect_noop[true]}, delete {[event_20191208][_doc][sjdos]}, update {[event_20191209][event][yyy], doc_as_upsert[false], upsert[index {[null][_doc][null], source[{"haha":"haha","jaja":"jaja"}]}], scripted_upsert[false], detect_noop[true]}
```

My goal is to match every separate request out of the bulk requests string, i.e to get strings like:

```
index {[event_20191209][event][null], source[{"haha":"haha","jaja":"jaja"}]},
update {[event_20191209][event][xxx], doc_as_upsert[false], doc[index {[null][_doc][null], source[{"haha":"haha","jaja":"jaja"}]}], scripted_upsert[false], detect_noop[true]},
delete {[event_20191208][_doc][sjdos]},
update {[event_20191209][event][yyy], doc_as_upsert[false], upsert[index {[null][_doc][null], source[{"haha":"haha","jaja":"jaja"}]}], scripted_upsert[false], detect_noop[true]}
```

And my pattern expression is `[a-z]+\s\{.+?\}[,\w\t\r\n]+?` which works fine on a Javascript based regular expression online tester like below:
[image]

However, when I copied this pattern expression to my Java code, the output was not what I expected. It was like this: [image][image]

So I realized there exists some differences between Javascript and Java regular expression engine, but I cannot figure out how to update my expression so that it could work well in Java after so much coding and googling.

I would be so grateful if someone could give me some favor or hint for this.

Comment: This grammar does not look regular. Make a real parser instead.

Comment: Please include your java code. Could be it's simply an issue of using the wrong method (for example, 'matches' instead of 'find'), misunderstanding the API, or getting backslash escapes wrong.

Comment: Thanks for checking out. The java code is now available

Answer (score 0):

After a short nap, I found epiphany. I was a fool in the morning....
The workaround is so easy to implement. Elasticsearch has well overridden toString() for us.
[image]